# TTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report Message The requested resource [/Servlet1/aaa] is not available

Tags: servlets, mapping, http-status-code-404

I have created one servlet program

```
package modern;

import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/aaa")
public class Login1 extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        
        System.out.println("hello");
        
    }
}








<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="aaa">clickme</a>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me findouting the solution for this programme of servlet i have been trying to solve this problems from two days still i am unable to solve this problem
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVZJZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT5ko.png)